# itgenoda131 "The server is currently unavailable" on Exact Online with join in query

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

Running a query with a join with `join_set` on Exact Online `Items`, I receive an:

```
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state. (https://start.exactonline.be/api/v1/261941/logistics/Items?$select=*&filter=((ID eq guid...
```

[image: Picture of https error with OData call on Exact Online]

This error occurs after approximately 20 minutes of API calls. When I execute the API call in isolation using a browser, the error does not occur.

How can I workaround this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by an unknown reason; it seems that the Exact Online API stack gets a little unstable after some time of intense requests.

The following options are known to work:

1. Do not use a `join_set` in your query, but use a full join. Yes, that one will run longer and cause a lot more calls depending on the environment, but the API stack does not get unstable.
2. Decrease the maximum number of join_set values of the OData provider attribute `join-set-points-per-request`. Normally it is 100. In general values such as '50' ensure that the query works although it now runs the double amount of API calls.